# Principal curvature of a surface defined by an equation

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

Let be $S$ a set of points $ (x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R^3}$ that satisfy the equation $x^3+y^2+z^2=1$. Calculate the main curvatures and Gaussian curvature at the points $p_1=(1,0,0)$, $p_2=(0,1,0)$ e $p_3=(0,0,1)$.

I want to know if this is correct:

We have that the tangent plane in $p_1$ is generated by $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ (from the Kernel of $dg_{p_1}$ where $g=x^3+y^2+z^2-1$), then we have that  $k_1= <N(p_1),\gamma_1''(0)>$ and $k_2= <N(p_1),\gamma_2''(0)>$ (where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are the two main curvatures and $N$ is the Gauss Map, in this case $N=\frac{dg}{||dg||}$) where $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ are two curves in $S$ that $\gamma_1(0)=\gamma_2(0)=p_1$ and $\gamma'_1(0)=(0,1,0)$,$\gamma'_2(0)=(0,0,1)$. We have $N(p_1)=(1,0,0)$, if we choose $\gamma_1(t)=((1-t^2)^{1/3},t,0)$ and $\gamma_2(t)=((1-t^2)^{1/3},0,t)$, we obtained $k_1=k_2=-2/3$, then Gaussian curvature is $4/9$.

Doing the same with $p_2$ we obtained $k_1=0$ and $k_2=-1$, so $K(p_2)=0$ and doing the same with $p_3$ we obtained $k_1=0$ and $k_2=-1$, so $K(p_3)=0$.

Comment: And what basis of the tangent plane i have to choose to have principal direction?

Comment: I think i found another way, i will write that, wait

Comment: The part with the isometry is right?

Answer (score 2):

Guys i think i undestand what do you mean:

for example if we consider the surfaces that is the image of the parametrizzazion $\varphi: (0, +\infty) \times (0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined as $\varphi(u,v)=(\frac{1}{2}u^2,\frac{1}{2}v^2,u-v)$, if we want to calculate the principal direction in $\varphi(1,1)=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0)$ we have that $w_1=\dfrac{\partial\varphi}{\partial u}(1,1)=(1,0,1)$ and $w_2=\dfrac{\partial\varphi}{\partial v}(1,1)=(0,1,-1)$ and the representation matrix of $dN_p$ compared to this basis is
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{2}{3 \sqrt3} & \frac{1}{3 \sqrt3} \\ 
-\frac{1}{3 \sqrt3} & -\frac{2}{3 \sqrt3} \end{pmatrix}. 
$$
that is not diagonal, so $\dfrac{\partial\varphi}{\partial u}(1,1)$ and $\dfrac{\partial\varphi}{\partial v}(1,1)$  are not the principal direction in this case. But i can diagonalize the matrix, infact consider
$$
H=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\ 
\sqrt3-2 & -\sqrt3-2 \end{pmatrix}. 
$$
we have
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{1}{3} & 0 \\ 
0 & -\frac{1}{3} \end{pmatrix}=
H^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{2}{3 \sqrt3} & \frac{1}{3 \sqrt3} \\ 
-\frac{1}{3 \sqrt3} & -\frac{2}{3 \sqrt3} \end{pmatrix}
H
$$
and so the principal directions are $w_1+(\sqrt3-2)w_2=(1,\sqrt3-2,3-\sqrt3)$ and $w_1+(-\sqrt3-2)w_2=(1,-\sqrt3-2,3+\sqrt3)$.

Answer (score 1):

We start with $p_1=(1,0,0)$ and consider the parametrization $\varphi_1: \mathbb{R}^2/S^1 \to S$ defined as $\varphi_1(y,z)=((1-y^2-z^2)^{1/3},y,z)$. Notice that $\varphi_1(0,0)=p_1$, and moreover, $\dfrac{\partial\varphi_1}{\partial y}(0,0)=(0,1,0)$ and $\dfrac{\partial\varphi_1}{\partial z}(0,0)=(0,0,1)$ are the principal directions in $p_1$. Then, continue the reasoning as you did to find the principal curvatures at $p_1$.

For $p_2=(0,1,0)$ consider the parametrization $\varphi_2: \mathbb{R}^2/{(x,z)|x^3+z^2=1} \to S$ defined as $\varphi_2(x,z)=(x,\sqrt(1-x^3-z^2),z)$. Notice that $\varphi_2(0,0)=p_2$, and moreover, $\dfrac{\partial\varphi_2}{\partial x}(0,0)=(1,0,0)$ and $\dfrac{\partial\varphi_2}{\partial y}(0,0)=(0,0,1)$ are the principal directions in $p_2$. Then, continue the reasoning as you did to find the principal curvatures at $p_2$.

In the end $p_3=(0,0,1)$ consider the parametrization $\varphi_3: \mathbb{R}^2/{(x,z)|x^3+y^2=1} \to S$ defined as $\varphi_3(x,y)=(x,y,\sqrt(1-x^3-y^2))$. Notice that $\varphi_3(0,0)=p_3$, and moreover, $\dfrac{\partial\varphi_3}{\partial x}(0,0)=(1,0,0)$ and $\dfrac{\partial\varphi_3}{\partial y}(0,0)=(0,1,0)$ are the principal directions in $p_3$. Then, continue the reasoning as you did to find the principal curvatures at $p_3$.

Comment: Beacuse $\varphi_1$ is a parametrizzation and so the partial derivates are the principal direction in a point (this sayed my professor)

Comment: You misunderstood your professor. You may have lucked out here, but you won't luck out if you move to a nearby point. I don't know what textbook your professor is following, but you can download my differential geometry text (freely available at the link in my profile) and see if that helps a bit.

Comment: I know that principal direction are the autospace generated by the ortonormal autovetctors of the differential of the gauss map, but in the case of parametrizzation they coincide with the partial derivates.

Comment: No, that's false. They coincide only at the single point $p_1$. But why? You can argue *geometrically* that these are principal directions at that point, but you must first understand what things mean.

Comment: it's an ombelical point

Comment: Yes, that's true, but what will you do at $p_2$ or $p_3$?

Comment: and in $p_2$ and $p_3$ ?

Comment: idk i see an excercise done by my professor in the cylinder where there are no ombelical point and it used my argomentation to find the principal curvature (i.e. he calculated the partial derivates of a parametrizzazion in that point and then he did what i have done in the question)